# laravel 4.2 object function return wrong value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-4.2

I have simple question here.

```
$order = Order::where('unique_id', $id)->first();
$canPickup = $order->canPickup();
$order->payment_id = Input::get('payment_id');
$order->save();

$order2 = Order::where('unique_id', $id)->first();  

$canPickup;  //return false
$order->canPickup();  //return false  
$order2->canPickup();  //return true
```

Why `$order->canPickup();` differs form `$order2->canPickup();` how I can achieve this function to return new value without creating new instance? Thanks

Update:

In canPickup() method i use paymentType relationship:

```
public function paymentType()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('PaymentType', 'payment_id');
}
```

And in same method I have these results. Why these values differs?

```
Debugbar::warning($this->payment_id); //return 3
Debugbar::warning($this->paymentType->id); //return old value 1.
```

Comment: what is `canPickup` method?
post the implementation

Comment: Did you try to execute `->canPickup()` after the `save()` in the `$order`?

Comment: I think is because you update just the attribute `payment_id` but not the objet `PaymentType` I find this related topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23642950/reloading-model-in-laravel

Comment: @vyckiuz can you please update your question with `canPickup()` method code?