# Eloquent - Strange behavior on save

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, lumen

I'm saving a record and then returning the values from database and Eloquent is not returning all of the values.

Example:

If I have a MySQL table called `names` like this:

```
| ID                         | Date                                | Name         |
|----------------------------|-------------------------------------|--------------|
| AUTO INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY | TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | VARCHAR(100) |
```

and I have an eloquent model called `Names`

and then I save and return like this:

```
function save($sName) {
    $oName = new Names();
    $oName->Name = $sName;

    $oName->save();

    $oReturn = new stdClass();
    $oReturn->Name = $oName->Name;
    $oReturn->Date = $oName->Date;
    return $oReturn;
}
```

It returns:

```
echo json_encode(save("Test")); // {"Name": "Test", "Date": null}
```

Is this normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is normal. Eloquent doesn't save and then do another query to select all the data for the record it just inserted.

Comment: I can save and then find by ID, but isn't there a way to do it in one step provided by eloquent?

Comment: You can call `->fresh()` and it should load the data from database. `... $oName->save(); $oName->fresh();`

Comment: Better yet, since your column `Date` is pretty much same as `created_at` you could tell Laravel to look for `created_at` in column `Date` - [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010435/laravel-custom-timestamp-column-names). That way Laravel will attach a timestamp to Date by default when a new model is saved and you won't need to do an additional query to get this result.

Comment: I agree with @devk, but it seems that author doesn't requre `updated_at` field of some analog of this field. There is no proper way to disable one of the automatic "timestamps" field in Laravel, only by using `boot` method of the model and setting desired parameter manually (as I wrote in my answer). In this case there is no need to say, that you should `const CREATED_AT = 'date';` in your model to re-define default field name for creation date `created_at`.

Comment: @devk You're right, but you must reset  or return the `$oName->fresh()`, because it doesn't update the model attributes, so what I did is `$oName = $oName->fresh()`, there's an answer related [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27748794/3541922)

Answer (score 1):

You can manually set field `date`, just add this code into your mode:

```
public static function boot()
{
    static::creating(function ($model) {
        $model->date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    });
}
```

You will avoid second DB request for selecting inserted item. Just be carefull with timezones when you're using `date` function.

Also you can use `getAttributes()` Eloquent method and get rid of stdClass:

```
function save($sName)
{
    $oName = new Names();
    $oName->Name = $sName;
    $oName->save();
    return $oName->getAttributes();
}
```